# Can't get Xpath to only output some TD's

Tags: dom, xpath, screen-scraping, screen

It's probably really easy if you know how, but I don't, and after spending hours Googling it I have to ask some "real" programmers, as I'm obviously not one.

I can't seem to find a tutorial or a code example that'll work for me. Let's say I just wanted to output the "EuroDiesel 10" TR (scroll halfway down to find it) and then I only want data from TD number 1 and 9. How would I go about doing that?

I also want to add the output data to a SQL DB with a date stamp as well as update it once a day. I assume this can be done with a Cron Job, is this correct and should a make a job for each price list I want to harvest data from or could I do it in a single script (the sites are very different)?

First of all I just need the correct data. This is what I got so far.

```
<?php 
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$date = date("j. F, Y");
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www3.statoil.com/mar/kbh00438.nsf/UNID/8C81E46A6EC8BA3BC12578C0002FFF5A?OpenDocument');
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$aTag = $xpath->query('//p[@class="text"]');

foreach($aTag as $val) {
    echo $date, '', $val->plaintext. "". utf8_decode(trim($val->nodeValue, "")) . "<br />\n";
}
?>
```

I hope you guys can help me out, just learning here...

Thanks!
Art

Comment: The major issue you can experience here is on the HTML document you are trying to parse, which is not well-formed. Even if XML is not mandatory for the `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile`, this can cause problems to `DOMXPath` class.

Comment: Agree! Definitely not an easy HTMl document to work with.

Answer (score 0):

As for the XPath, I think `/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[normalize-space(td[1]) = 'EuroDiesel 10']/td[position() = 1 or position() = 9]` should do. Then access `$val->textContent` instead of nodeValue.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I get an " unexpected T_STRING" error, but I see the logic, so perhaps I can get it to work with a little modification.